# How to get current store group id?

Tags: magento

I am trying to get a store group id? 
Like i can access store view id, is there a way to get store group id the same way like `Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()` this only gives store view id

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out, following brings the store group id for a current store view:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getGroupId()
```